# GTM tracking and firing a trigger if someone goes to a specific URL

Tags: google-tag-manager

Hi is it possible for google tag manager to track if someone goes to an external website WITHOUT clicking on a link on your website?

I know theres a way of having outbound link clicks tracked but basically without going into a lot of detail as to why.
I want to be able to track if someone goes from one of my checkout pages directly to Paypal and not just relying on a button press because a button press doesn't mean they were a sale.

I know going to Paypal doesn't either but its a long story to why I want to do this if its possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. You cannot track anything on a foreign website without implementing some code into that website (after all, if I could somehow track what is happening on other websites, it would be a huge privacy and security issue).

If you want to track something on the external website you'd have to ask the owner to implement something there (Paypal is unlikely to do that).

Alternatively, you could go server-to-server, [use the Paypal API to get the transaction to see if it went through](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/) and then send an measurement hit to GA with the transaction data, but that would be very complicated and would circumvent Google Tag Manager (and indeed the browser) completely.